# How to getting String from adapter to fragment?

Tags: android, fragment, adapter

Umm, i like to parsing string from adapter to fragment, how can i do that?? because i got a space string on my apps.

this the code from my adapter

**Adapter**

```
public class listAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<listAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private Simpleway simpleway = new Simpleway();
private ArrayList<DataFirebase> dataList;
private AppCompatActivity someActivity;
private TitleFragment fragmentTitle = new TitleFragment();
private ModelData model = new ModelData();

public listAdapter(ArrayList<DataFirebase> dataList, AppCompatActivity someActivity) {
    this.dataList = dataList;
    this.someActivity = someActivity;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_label, viewGroup, false);

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, int positions) {
    final DataFirebase labelList = dataList.get(positions);

    viewHolder.textLabel.setText(labelList.getLabel());
    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String enough = labelList.getLabel();
            model.setLabel(enough);
            simpleway.toastMessage(someActivity, model.getLabel());
            someActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_right, R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_right)
                    .replace(R.id.container_layout, fragmentTitle)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();

        }
    });

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public LinearLayout linearLabel;
    public TextView textLabel;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textLabel = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_label);
        linearLabel = itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLabel);


    }

}
}
```

So Mostly my code for adapter will openup my titlefragment and passing the string using pojo but, i didnt get any data String on my pojo so here look at my TitleFragment class

**TitleFragment**

```
public class TitleFragment extends BaseFragment {

private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private RecyclerView titleRecycleView;
private ArrayList<DataFirebase> listLabel;
private com.example.parzival.flashcard.adapter.titleAdapter titleAdapter;
private DataFirebase dataFirebase = new DataFirebase();
private ModelData modelData = new ModelData();

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_title, container, false);
    findView(view);
    check();
//        setDataToList(view);
    initListener(view);
    putLayoutManager(view);
    return view;
}

private void check() {
    if (modelData.getLabel().equals("")) {
        simpleway.toastMessage(getContext(), "null");
    } else {
        simpleway.toastMessage(getContext(), modelData.getLabel());
    }
}

private void setDataToList(View view) {
    databaseReference.child(modelData.getLabel()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            listLabel = new ArrayList<>();

            for (DataSnapshot dataSnap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                DataFirebase dataText = dataSnap.getValue(DataFirebase.class);
                dataText.setTitle(dataSnap.getKey());
                listLabel.add(dataText);
            }

            titleAdapter = new titleAdapter(listLabel, TitleFragment.this);
            titleRecycleView.setAdapter(titleAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.print(databaseError.getDetails() + "" + databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });

}

private void putLayoutManager(View view) {
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    titleRecycleView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    titleRecycleView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
}

@Override
public void findView(View view) {
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    titleRecycleView = view.findViewById(R.id.titleRecycleView);

}

@Override
public void initListener(View view) {

}

}
```

And after i run the only thing i got a null object from `model.getLabel()` how?
i already input the String on model, isn't it? at `model.setLabel(enough)`
so why i got this error?

**EDIT**

I try to explain more about my activiy maybe .The main problem is i'm using a fragment to pass data and i try to post some of my Activity class as well.

**ListActivity**

```
public class ListActivity extends BaseActivity{

    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private RecyclerView labelRecycleView;
    private ArrayList<DataFirebase> listLabel;
    private listAdapter listAdapter;
    private Button bInput;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
        findView();
        setDataToList();
        initListener();
        putLayoutManager();
    }

    private void setDataToList() {
        simpleway.progressDialog(ListActivity.this);
        databaseReference.child("Username").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                listLabel = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    DataFirebase modelClass = dataSnap.getValue(DataFirebase.class);
                    modelClass.setLabel(dataSnap.getKey());
                    listLabel.add(modelClass);
                }
                listAdapter = new listAdapter(listLabel, ListActivity.this);
                labelRecycleView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                simpleway.stopProgressDialog();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println(databaseError.getDetails() + " " + databaseError.getMessage());
                simpleway.stopProgressDialog();
            }
        });
    }

    private void putLayoutManager() {
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        labelRecycleView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        labelRecycleView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    }

    @Override
    public void findView() {
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        labelRecycleView = findViewById(R.id.listRecyclerVIew);
        bInput = findViewById(R.id.inputData);
    }


    @Override
    public void initListener() {
        bInput.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                simpleway.startnextActivity(ListActivity.this, InputActivity.class);
            }
        });
    }

   }
```

I use `someActivity` that had been passed by ListActivity not a Fragment that's why

Comment: use interface as a callback from adapter to fragment

Comment: you mean how you add onItemClickListener to adapter?

Comment: you want to remove whitespace from strings in adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solutions**

i had already try using the answered questions and got stuck. I think its mostly used for Activity (Correct me if i'm wrong). So the only way i solve this case by using argument

```
            String enough = labelList.getLabel();
            TitleFragment titleFragment = new TitleFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = someActivity
                    .getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
```

after that i use Bundle to put an Argument

```
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("Check", enough);
            titleFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

and then i try open up my Fragment

```
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, 
R.anim.exit_to_right, R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_right)
                    .replace(R.id.container_layout, titleFragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
```

so i take my string using argument on title fragment

```
private void setDataToList() {
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        String newText = getArguments().getString("Check");
        simpleway.toastMessage(mContext, newText);
    } else {
        simpleway.toastMessage(mContext, "Failed");
    }

}
```

and its done

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface CallBackListener {
    void onCallBack(String data);// pass any parameter in your onCallBack which you want to return
}
```

inside fragment create anonymous object

```
  CallBackListener listener=new CallBackListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCallBack(String data) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            };
```

from your adapter pass the reference of listener and inside onClick call the onCallBack(data);

Answer (score 0):

First create an interface

```
public interface PassBack {
    void valueFromAdapter(String value);
}
```

Then implement this in your Fragment like this

```
public class TitleFragment extends BaseFragment implements PassBack{

private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private RecyclerView titleRecycleView;
private ArrayList<DataFirebase> listLabel;
private com.example.parzival.flashcard.adapter.titleAdapter titleAdapter;
private DataFirebase dataFirebase = new DataFirebase();
private ModelData modelData = new ModelData();

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_title, container, false);
    findView(view);
    check();
//        setDataToList(view);
    initListener(view);
    putLayoutManager(view);
    return view;
}

private void check() {
    if (modelData.getLabel().equals("")) {
        simpleway.toastMessage(getContext(), "null");
    } else {
        simpleway.toastMessage(getContext(), modelData.getLabel());
    }
}

private void setDataToList(View view) {
    databaseReference.child(modelData.getLabel()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            listLabel = new ArrayList<>();

            for (DataSnapshot dataSnap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                DataFirebase dataText = dataSnap.getValue(DataFirebase.class);
                dataText.setTitle(dataSnap.getKey());
                listLabel.add(dataText);
            }

            titleAdapter = new titleAdapter(listLabel, TitleFragment.this);
            titleRecycleView.setAdapter(titleAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.print(databaseError.getDetails() + "" + databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });

}

private void putLayoutManager(View view) {
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    titleRecycleView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    titleRecycleView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
}

@Override
public void findView(View view) {
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    titleRecycleView = view.findViewById(R.id.titleRecycleView);

}

@Override
public void initListener(View view) {

}

@Override
public void valueFromAdapter(String value) {
//here you will get the value 
}

}
```

Then in your adapter use it like this

```
public class listAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<listAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private Simpleway simpleway = new Simpleway();
private ArrayList<DataFirebase> dataList;
private AppCompatActivity someActivity;
private TitleFragment fragmentTitle = new TitleFragment();
private ModelData model = new ModelData();

public listAdapter(ArrayList<DataFirebase> dataList, AppCompatActivity someActivity) {
    this.dataList = dataList;
    this.someActivity = someActivity;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_label, viewGroup, false);

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, int positions) {
    final DataFirebase labelList = dataList.get(positions);

    viewHolder.textLabel.setText(labelList.getLabel());
    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String enough = labelList.getLabel();
            model.setLabel(enough);
            simpleway.toastMessage(someActivity, model.getLabel());
            someActivity.valueFromAdapter(enough)//this is how you send your value

        }
    });

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public LinearLayout linearLabel;
    public TextView textLabel;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textLabel = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_label);
        linearLabel = itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLabel);


    }

}
}
```

Comment: i try to implements your sollutions. But, i can't call the method valueFromAdapter when i try to use `someActivity`

Answer (score 0):

**In your Adapter**

A. Create Interface

```
public interface Listener {
  void callback(String data);
}
```

B. Create Field

```
 private Listener listener;
```

C. Initialize listener on onCreateViewHolder

```
listener =  (Listener)viewGroup.getContext()
```

D. Set Value

```
 String enough = labelList.getLabel();
 listener.callback(enough) // Set the value here
```

**In you Fragment**

(One Way )

6. Implement the interface
7. in the callback method you can get the data.

(Another Way )

1. Directly implement listener in the  onCreate anonymous object

Comment: i got an error when i try to implements your solutions `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.parzival.flashcard.activity.ListActivity cannot be cast to com.example.parzival.flashcard.fragment.PassBack`

Comment: you are getting ClassCastException that means interface not initialize properly.
Pass the context from Adapter and initialize to that interface.This way you can see the result. If you don't like to pass context in adapter , just follow the steps C like listener =  (Listener)new TitleFragment()